# Why does the US have many top-level web domains?

Tags: united-states, military, technology, computers, internet

Why does the US have top-level domains like *.gov*, *.mil* and others, while other nations can only use second level domains for their government agencies? It might seem an easy question, but I think it is interesting to know details that possibly are not written on Wikipedia.

*Migrated from **networkengineering.stackexchange.com**.*

*Migrated from **retrocomputing.stackexchange.com**.*

Comment: Because ARPANET was a US government sponsored project, but I'm not sure I'd call the second level domains "bad".

Comment: Same reason that postal stamps for all nations *except Britain* must have country codes. First mover's privilege. see [quora](https://www.quora.com/Why-do-Chinese-and-American-websites-not-use-country-code-domains)  - although someone could probably find a better citation

Comment: [RFC 920](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc920) set out the specifications of [generic top-level domains](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generic_top-level_domain) in 1984, administered by [DARPA](https://www.darpa.mil/policy/visitor-information), which as @Semaphore points out, is a US Government agency.

Comment: @Spencer this RFC doesn't point out that those domains must be used by US only. Infact .org is described like others, but can be used by any country/organization still today. The decision to make them US-only was taken in the future probably.

Comment: @JDoe More likely, there was no "decision".  It was just assumed, since they were administered by the US military.

Comment: In fact, .MIL is run by DDN, which is the WAN of US DoD.

Comment: @gktscrk that's an useless motivation for closing a question. Even a simple question can be answered with lots of useful material and details.

Comment: Erm? I didn't vote to close this...

Comment: Does two - .gov and .mil - really count as many?  Also, the answer seems fairly obvious, sort of asking why most computer interaction was, and to a considerable extent still is, in ASCII.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The Internet [started as a project of the US Department of Defense's Advanced Research Projects Agency](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_the_Internet), under the name "ARPANET".  The [original five top-level domains](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc920) (.com, .org, .edu, .gov, and .mil) date from 1984, when the network was still almost exclusively a US-only project.

Comment: I went and did a wee bit of research on that "almost". It looks like [University College, London](http://www0.cs.ucl.ac.uk/csnews/internet_pioneers.html) was on the ARPANET for a while. Couldn't find anyone else on a quick search, but I'd be shocked if there wasn't a Canadian university or two on there. But otherwise, yes it would have been almost entirely US-resident nodes.

Comment: @T.E.D., NORSAR (Norway) was also an off-and-on part of ARPANET at the time.

Comment: Yup, you called it. [Those were the first two](https://www.historyofinformation.com/detail.php?id=904)